# fileToSTring keeps on returning " "

Tags: java, file-io

I managed to get this code to compile with out error. But somehow it did not return the strings that I wrote inside file1.txt and file.txt that I pass its path through str1 and str2. My objective is to use this open source library to measure the similarity between strings contains inside 2 text files.

Inside the its Javadoc, its states that ...

```
public static java.lang.StringBuffer fileToString(java.io.File f)

private call to load a file and return its content as a string.

Parameters:
    f - a file for which to load its content 
Returns:
    a string containing the files contents or "" if empty or not present
```

Here's is my modified code trying to use the FileLoader function, but fails to return the strings inside the file. The end result keeps on returning me the "" . I do not know where is my fault:

```
   package uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics;
   import java.io.File;
   import uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.similaritymetrics.*;
   import uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.utils.*;


public class SimpleExample {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    if(args.length != 2) {

        usage();

    } else {

        String str1 = "arg[0]";
        String str2 = "arg[1]";

        File objFile1 = new File(str1);

        File objFile2 = new File(str2);

        FileLoader obj1 = new FileLoader();
        FileLoader obj2 = new FileLoader();

        str1 = obj1.fileToString(objFile1).toString();

        str2 = obj2.fileToString(objFile2).toString();


        System.out.println(str1);            
        System.out.println(str2);


        AbstractStringMetric metric = new MongeElkan();

        //this single line performs the similarity test

        float result = metric.getSimilarity(str1, str2);

        //outputs the results

        outputResult(result, metric, str1, str2);

    }

}


private static void outputResult(final float result, final AbstractStringMetric metric, final String str1, final String str2) {

    System.out.println("Using Metric " + metric.getShortDescriptionString() + " on strings \"" + str1 + "\" & \"" + str2 + "\" gives a similarity score of " + result);



}



private static void usage() {

    System.out.println("Performs a rudimentary string metric comparison from the arguments given.\n\tArgs:\n\t\t1) String1 to compare\n\t\t2)String2 to compare\n\n\tReturns:\n\t\tA standard output (command line of the similarity metric with the given test strings, for more details of this simple class please see the SimpleExample.java source file)");

}
```

}

Update: I have modified the code, but it gives me this error:

```
SimpleExample.java:79: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable arg
location: class uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.SimpleExample
        String str1 = arg[0];
                      ^
SimpleExample.java:80: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable arg
location: class uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.SimpleExample
        String str2 = arg[1];
                      ^
```

Comment: @karikari, I had a typo, try `args` instead of `arg`. Also, where is `FileLoader` class coming from?

Comment: @anthony, the FileLoader class comes from the simmetric.jar, an open source library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your Java program through the command line, it seems you aren't retrieving the arguments correctly,

```
String str1 = "arg[0]";
String str2 = "arg[1]";
```

Should be,

```
String str1 = args[0];
String str2 = args[1];
```